# How can I detect a virtual keyboard switch and in which computer the user is typing?

Tags: c#, keyboard, virtualization

Virtual keyboard switch programs (like Kavoom or Mouse without borders) allow you to control more than one PC from a single keyboard.

I detect typed keystrokes using a global keyboard hook: how can I detect if the user is typing inside in an application inside the local computer or into the remote computer?

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't that be handled by the virtual keyboard program?

Comment: Well the point is that keystrokes arrive to the main computer the keyboard is attached to even when I'm typing into the other computer.